# Load data only once in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a project using AngularJS and I want to load the data once in my Angular controller. My code works, but sometimes it shows me empty data.

Here is my code:

```
 if(!$scope.locations){
      $scope.promise = pricingService.getIPVPNLocations().then(function(response){
           $scope.locations = response.data;
        })
  }
```

Here is the view:

```
 <select ng-model="pricing.ipvpnLocation" ng-init="pricing.ipvpnLocation = location[0].uuid" ng-options="location as location.name for location in locations |  orderBy:'name' track by location.uuid ">
            <option value="">Select Location </option>

        </select>
```

My service looks like:

```
this.getIPVPNLocations = function (epuuid,serviceuuid) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = '/pricing/getIPVPNLocations/'+epuuid+"/"+serviceuuid;
        $http.get(url).
            then(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve({data: response.data.message, status: response.data.statusCode});
            }).
            catch(function (response) {
                deferred.reject(response);
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use services since they are singleton. Just create a local variable in the service and it will remain there through​ out application life cycle

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more variable in your service which will hold locations data.

Goal is first to check if location data exist if not then make an ajax call.
Service will be..

```
.service('YourService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {

    var  locations = [];

    return {

        getLocations: function (epuuid,serviceuuid) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if(locations.length){
                 deferred.resolve(locations);
            }else{               
                var url = '/pricing/getIPVPNLocations/'+epuuid+"/"+serviceuuid;
                $http.get(url).
                    then(function (response) {
                        locations = response.data; //assuming that response.data is an array of locations
                        deferred.resolve(locations);
                    },function (reason) {
                        deferred.reject(reason);
                    }).
                    catch(function (response) {
                        deferred.reject(response);
                    });
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}])
```

In Controller

```
$scope.locations = [];    
YourService.getLocations(param1,param2).then(function(locations){
        $scope.locations = locations;
    },function(reason){
        console.log('Something wrong: ',reason);
    })
```